# Can I switch azure app service Publish Profile

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

In azure web app we have two option to publish our code:

1. Via Code
2. Via Docker image
   is there any way i can switch between this two.

Answer (score 2):

To switch the publish method from docker to code you can set the `linuxFxVersion` via Azure CLI. For example:

```
az webapp config set --name myWebApp --resource-group rgname --linux-fx-version 'DOTNETCORE|3.1'
```

[image]

To switch from code to docker you can just deploy a docker container and the web app will automatically switch to the docker publish method. For example:

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName rgName -Name myWebApp -ContainerImageName imageName:tag -ContainerRegistryUser userName -ContainerRegistryPassword  $passwordSecure -ContainerRegistryUrl url
```

[image]

I have not tested it for windows apps but I supect it will behave similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you select `Publish Profile` as `Connection Type` you cannot deploy docker image. Please check this:

- for `Azure Resource Manager` you can select container deployment:

[image]

- but for `Publish Profile` you don't have this choice:

[image]

The same apply for YAML version.

Comment: You are right in case of Azure resource manager we have to select the app service type but if we are going to create a app service from portal we will get a option of publish: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/host-a-web-app-with-azure-app-service/3-exercise-create-a-web-app-in-the-azure-portal?pivots=java

Comment: Yeah, but if you chose `Code` you want be able to switch to `Docker Image`, you simply need to delete and create a new resource. This is also reflected in Azure DevOps task.

Comment: @GauravRatnawat Not get your latest information, is Krzysztof Madej's answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT just wanted to confirm creating a resource is the only option we have in this case. TIA.

Comment: @GauravRatnawat I'm afraid that you can not change from code to container , but you can have two instances of your code, one using code and one using container within the same service app. You can refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62924348/is-it-possible-to-convert-the-publish-method-of-an-app-service-from-code-to-dock). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can not change from `code` to `container` , but you can have two instances of your code, one using code and one using container within the same service app. You can re-created your webapp with the same name but with a different deployment method in the portal.

For details , please refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62924348/is-it-possible-to-convert-the-publish-method-of-an-app-service-from-code-to-dock) with similar issue.